# Architecture for multiple Rails 3.2 applications/engines

Tags: architecture, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I come from the Java world and am a newbie to Rails. I have a developed a moderate sized Rails 3.2 business application. The time has come to develop a second application, as well as a "portal" application to allow users access to these and provide administrative user and role management.

Single sign-on is a requirement (log in once to the portal, then be able to access applications you have rights to) and there are many fundamental domain models that need to be shared across the applications. Also, the applications use mostly the same gems and the same CSS.

All applications will reside on the same server, and can share a database. There are two developers working on these apps, but only 1 app at a time (i.e. no teams greater than 1 person).

There seems to be three ways to architect this (without going the route of exposing common data access as services):

1. A single mega app, with namespaced (via modules and routes) models, controllers and views. Single git repo.
2. A single lightweight master rails app for the portal, containing shared models, views, controllers. Each business app is implemented as a mountable Rails engine. A git repo for the master app and each engine.
3. A single full engine with shared models, views, controllers. Rails apps for the portal and each business app, which all reference the full engine. The engine could contain all models I guess, like a shared Java DAO library. A git repo for the full engine and each of the apps.

The Java-like approach would be 3, and this seems to be the most rational approach. From what I've read, 2 is certainly possible, even though engines were intended to be used for common functionality that enhanced a master app (e.g. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)). I've seen 1 being implemented before, but not 2 or 3 for a portal + multiple web app architecture. Converting our existing app to an engine is painful but possible.

There are certain conveniences to having a single mega app and a single server: deployment is simplified, for example. But it does mean that the apps are not in their own repos and any changes to the code requires redeploying the entire codebase. This seems to work for combining smaller apps into a single mega app, but I doubt it scales to larger business apps, even if they share a lot of models.

Other than the articles [Migrating from a single Rails app to a suite of Rails engines](http://pivotallabs.com/migrating-from-a-single-rails-app-to-a-suite-of-rails-engines/) and [Rails Engine Patterns](http://www.slideshare.net/AndyMaleh/rails-engine-patterns), there seems to be little information available on this. Would appreciate some guidance from experienced Rails developers/architects.